# Are there any SOHO routers that can handle a 120 Mbit internet connection?

Tags: router

Are there any routers that can handle a 120 Mbit connection to the internet?

It would be in a family house.

Extra: Are there any solutions to get this speed over wireless? (64bitwep/802.11n/mimo/directional antenna-not omni/?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and this should help you decide: http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/router-charts/view

To answer your question below:

There are really 2 parts to the question then: You need to talk about WAN-LAN throughput, which you are saying is 120Mb (that is incredibly fast considering most cable is only around 20Mb...who is your provider...what country?). That was the number I was really worried about since a lot of home routers cannot do this since they are only worried about that market in the 0-50Mb sector. Your speed is still rare in homes. So that is the chart I sent you.

Other than that, you then have wireless speed, which is your internal networ...computer-to-computer. The B-band was only 11Mb, A-band 54Mb, G-band 54Mb, and now the new N-band at rates exceeding 100Mb, usually 150Mb. Many of these also run dual or quad signals, boosting the network speed to 300Mb or even 600Mb. The router you asked about claims 300Mb. That is sufficiently high enough that your Internet should not slow down.

Last caveat, you need an N-wireless network card, and sometimes you need specific cards from the same manufacturer to achieve the speeds above 150Mb with N. If your PC is older, it probably does not. Also, read the reviews, especially negative ones, for any device you want to buy...the ones for that device seem not-so-great.

http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/wireless80211/a/aa80211standard.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#802.11n

Comment: an asus rtn56u with wpa2/aes/63 char pass could really give me 120 Mbit bandwidth over wireless?

Comment: I will add the answer to this to my answer above...better formatting capabilities.